# Joining two tables and displaying results - php/mysql

Tags: php, sql

The following script successfully allows me to search a date and display all information in the 'JOBS' table relating to the time is was put on the system which is stored in the 'orderno' table.

```
// PUT your connection data HERE !

$DB_SERVER = 'localhost';
$DB_NAME = 'database';
$DB_USER = 'username';
$DB_PASS = '*********'; 

// opening a connection to the database
try
{
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$DB_SERVER.";dbname=".$DB_NAME.";charset=utf8", $DB_USER,    $DB_PASS, array(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) );
}
   catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
   }

$sql = 
"SELECT o.JobNumber, o.date_col, Job_Title, Handler
FROM orderno o
INNER JOIN JOBS j on (o.JobNumber = j.JobNo)
WHERE date_col = ?";

  // preparing the query
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

 // assembling the requested date
  $date = $_GET['year'] . '-' . $_GET['month'] . '-' . $_GET['day'];

// setting the parameter value  
$stmt->bindParam(1, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// executing the query 
$stmt->execute();

// returning the resultset
$resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ( count($resultSet) == 0 )     {
    echo "No records found for date ".$date;
}
   else {
   echo '<table border=1>';
    // writing the table header
echo '<tr>';
foreach($resultSet[0] as $key => $value) {        
    if (!is_numeric($key)) {
    echo '<TH>'.$key.'</TH>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
// writing the rows...
foreach($resultSet as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // each field...
    for($i = 0; $i < $stmt->columnCount(); $i++) {
        echo '<td>'.$row[$i].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
   }

?></center>
```

However, in the 'JOBS table, the 'Handler' is stored as a number. 
In the 'handler' table it shows the relating number but matches it with the FullName.

How do I link this script to the 'handler table' and display the FullName in this column rather than the number which is stored in the JOBS table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do another join `INNER JOIN HANDLER h ON h.row_id = j.Handler`, and then just add the `FUllName` to your `SELECT`

```
SELECT o.JobNumber, o.date_col, j.Job_Title, h.FullName
FROM orderno o
INNER JOIN JOBS j ON o.JobNumber = j.JobNo
INNER JOIN HANDLER h ON h.row_id = j.Handler
WHERE o.date_col = ?
```

Comment: If you have `date_col` in more than 1 of your tables, you will need to specify the table, or it is ambiguous - ie. `o.date_col`. I updated my answer with that.

Comment: The date_col is only in the orderno table. The code works but as soon as I try and get the handlers name (FullName) from the handlers table working rather than its number which is shown in the JOBS table. It stops displaying results :S

Comment: Then your query is most likely failing. Are you using the correct row identifier in `h.row_id = j.Handler` (ie, I put `row_id` as I did not know what your identifier was). Try running your query directly in MySQL to see if there are any errors.